# didPop() not accepting any arguments in flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator

I want to `setState()` of the widget after navigating from a particular widget,

for this, I am using route observer as mentioned in this official [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)

for the above requirement, I need to know the widget which I navigated from and if it matches the required widget then I will `setState()` in this widget.

in the docs `didPop()` takes the arguments `Route route, Route previous route`

but in the widget when passing the argument like

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with RouteAware {
   @override
   void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
      print("oh oooo yes");
   }
 }
```

flutter is giving the error

```
'_MainPageState.didPop' ('void Function(Route<dynamic>, Route<dynamic>)') isn't a valid override of 
 'RouteAware.didPop' ('void Function()').dart(invalid_override)
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `RouteAware` and `RouteObserver`.

`RouteAware`'s `didPop` does not receive any parameter. It is `RouteObserver`'s `didPop` that do.

The thing is, what is mixed in on widgets is `RouteAware`, not `RouteObserver`. As such, widgets do not receive the current/previous routes.

Consider subclassing `NavigatorObserver`/`RouteObserver` and bake something on your own if you need something advanced.

Comment: what do you mean by subclassing, could you provide simple example?